# Como hago que imprima los nombres guardados en los arreglos (lenguajec)

Tags: array, c

estoy haciendo un programa que solicita 5 nombres de estudiantes, sus notas y debe imprimirlas de forma ordenada. Pero no me imprime nada, he visto varios videos y no se que tengo mal

Este es lo que tengo hasta el momento

```
    /*Declare 2 vectores. Uno contendra el nombre de los estudiantes y el otro la calificacion final obtenida en el curso.
ordene de mayor a menor */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
     int i;
      char nombre[5];
      int nota[5];

      for (i=0; i<4;i++)
      {
          printf ("\nEscriba el nombre de los estudiantes: ");
          scanf ("%s", &nombre[i]);

          printf ("\nEscriba las notas de los estudiantes: ");
          scanf ("%d", nota[i]);
      }

      for (i=0; i<=4;i++)
      {
          printf ("\n Estudiante: %s ", nombre[i]);
          printf ("\n notas: %d ", nota[i]);
      }




  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recuerda que `char` permite almacenar un caracter. Un arreglo de caracteres permite almacenar varios (un string).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Una buena referencia es estudiar un poco sobre los [**algoritmos de ordenación**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordenamiento).

Dependiendo del orden de menor a mayor o de mayor a menor, los algoritmos de ordenación siguen un patrón definido para ayudar.
Ya sea ordenar strings o números enteros (int, float), son algoritmos que tienen cierto rendimiento en la ordenación, no todos son rápidos ya que la lógica requiere intercambio de posiciones y verificaciones que pueden llevar tiempo.

Entre ellos, el más simple es el [Bubble sort](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja), en resumen, recorre un conjunto de elementos varias veces y en cada pasada coloca en la parte superior el elemento más grande de la secuencia.

Entre algunas de las más simples se encuentra el "Bubble sort", en resumen, recorre un conjunto de elementos varias veces y en cada pasada coloca en la parte superior el elemento más grande de la secuencia.

El primer bucle iterará todos los elementos de la lista de notas.

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

El segundo bucle iterará sobre todos los elementos, excepto la última posición.

```
for (j = 0; j < 4 - i; j++)
```

En cada par de elementos adyacentes, el "Bubble sort" compara las notas. Si la primera nota es menor que la segunda nota, las notas se intercambian. `4 - i` es para evitar comparar dos elementos que ya han sido ordenados.

```
if (nota[j] < nota[j + 1])
```

Verifica si la primera nota es menor que la segunda nota. En caso afirmativo, se realizará el intercambio de notas.

```
int axn = nota[j];
nota[j] = nota[j + 1];
nota[j + 1] = axn;
```

Esta parte es igual al Bubble Sort, también compara los pares adyacentes y los intercambia si están fuera de orden.

```
char ax[50];
strcpy(ax, nombre[j]);
strcpy(nombre[j], nombre[j + 1]);
strcpy(nombre[j + 1], ax);
```

Bubble sort, lista

```
5,3,6,1
```

Primero compara 5 con 3, cambia de posición

```
3,5
```

Luego compara 5 con 6, no hay diferencia, no ocurre intercambio

```
3,5,6
```

Después compara 1 con 6, intercambia y luego compara 1 con 5 y cambia de posición, y así sucesivamente hasta organizar según la lógica:

*** Código**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  

int main() {
    int i, j;
    char nombre[5][50];  
    int nota[5];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("\nEscriba el nombre del estudiante %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", nombre[i]);

        printf("Escriba la nota del estudiante %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &nota[i]);
    }

    // Implementación  Bubble Sort  
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4 - i; j++) {
            if (nota[j] < nota[j + 1]) {
               
                int axn = nota[j];
                nota[j] = nota[j + 1];
                nota[j + 1] = axn;

           
                char ax[50];
                strcpy(ax, nombre[j]);
                strcpy(nombre[j], nombre[j + 1]);
                strcpy(nombre[j + 1], ax);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nEstudiantes ordenados por notas (de mayor a menor):\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Estudiante: %s - Nota %d \n", nombre[i], nota[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No tenia idea de que llevaban ese orden, estoy estudiando por mi cuenta jeje

Comment: Muchas Gracias por su ayuda y dedicar un poco de su tiempo a mi problema

Answer (score 1):

```
char nombre[5];
```

Aquí has declarado un array de tipo `char` de tamaño 5, es decir, es un grupo de 5 elementos de tipo `char`. Dado que un `char` puede almacenar únicamente un caracter .... en `nombre` únicamente podrás guardar 5 caracteres sueltos o una cadena de **hasta 4** caracteres (recuerda que las cadenas deben terminar por `\0`).

Para poder almacenar 5 nombres necesitas crear un array doble:

```
char nombre[5][200];
```

Ahora ya la variable podrá almacenar hasta 5 cadenas de caracteres con una longitud máxima de 199 cada una de ellas.

Por otro lado, como has podido comprobar, en C no hay un tipo específico para las cadenas de caracteres, son básicamente array de tipo char. Esto convierte cualquier cadena de caracteres en un **puntero**.

La función `scanf` necesita de un puntero para poder acceder a la memoria de las variables. Dado que una cadena es en sí misma un puntero, no necesitas obtener la dirección de memoria de la variable, como sí harías con el resto de tipos:

```
scanf("%s", nombre[i]);
```

En cambio, `nota[i]` no es un puntero, sino un entero. Es decir, para poder almacenar valores en `nota[i]` sí que necesitas usar `&`. `scanf` necesita obtener la dirección de memoria donde se almacena el entero.

Otra forma de verlo sería así:

```
scanf("%d", nota+i);
```

En este caso no hace falta `&` porque `nota` actúa como puntero, y la variable `i` es el desplazamiento sobre el inicio del array.

Es decir, `nota+i == &nota[i]` y, por tanto, `*(nota+i) == nota[i]`

Por terminar de aclararlo, en el caso de `nombre[i]`, no hace falta usar el & porque `nombre` es un array doble, luego `nombre[i]` es un array simple. Los arrays decaen (se pueden convertir automáticamente por el compilador) a punteros.

Un saludo